How to copy a variable's value to the clipboard in Ghidra debugger
When I hover over an array variable in a Ghidra debugging session, I get a pop-up that looks like this:

The pop-up is called a variable hover in the Ghidra documentation, which explains what all of the values mean. What I am most interested in is the 248 bytes that make up the array. How can I get those 248 bytes out of Ghidra and onto the clipboard to paste into another program for further analysis?

Did you try to simply select the bytes with your mouse and use ctrl-C or the context menu to copy?

That's the first thing I tried. They're not selectable and there's no context menu.
